# Storing DB versions in Private RPM Repo the best option?

Tags: database, version, load-balancing, rpm

I am running a clustered network of servers each with their own (identical) application and database. I have a separate server which contains just a database (same data).

Each day I run a task that updates the separate database, which I then take a dump of and deploy to all of my other servers. Exporting the dump file and importing onto each server is a hassle. I am planning on migrating to using an RPM repository to contain the data and script as a package.

The advantage of the RPM solution is that each daily update will be versioned, so it would be easy to revert to any specific day, and it would be a self contained update.

Are there any downsides to my solution?

Is there a better solution that you can think of?